# Add or omit "can", "could" or "will" when making a suggestion or giving an instruction?

Tags: modal-verbs

When we make a suggestion or give people instructions, we can add "can" or "could" and use "will" in the next clause.

What are the differences if we add or omit them?

---

**Example 1:**

With **can/could** and **will**

> Now, we are about to do an exercise. You **can/could** warm up a little by moving your body, and I **will** show you and teach you the moves.

**Example 2:**

Without **can/could** but with **will**

> Now, we are about to do an exercise. You warm up a little by moving your body, and I **will** show you and teach you the moves.

**Example 3:**

Without **can/could** and without **will**

> Now, we are about to do an exercise. You warm up a little by moving your body, and I show you and teach you the moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With both:**

> You can warm up... I will show you

This is a suggestion first, and then a statement of futurity. It is *possible* (or *permitted*) that you could do a warm-up; whether you do or not, the teacher will show you the moves.

Using **could** is not idiomatic here. Really the proper word is **may**, which gives permission, instead of **can**, which describes ability—this is the classic student-teacher exchange of "Can I go to the restroom?" / "I don't know, can you?" But in casual speech we say **can**, which might sound less formal than **may**.

---

**Without "can:"**

> You warm up... I will show you

Now the warming-up is an imperative. The teaching is still a statement of futurity: the speaker is *telling* you to warm up, and [then] they will teach you.

---

**Without either:**

> You warm up... I show you

The imperative is still an imperative. The teacher's statement is no longer grammatically correct; it sounds like the stereotypical "Asian person speaking broken English" from older books and shows. If the teacher means to say they will demonstrate *while* you warm up they should say that: "...while I show you." If they mean that they will wait until after you warm up, the "will" is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me. Your explanation is very clear. There is something I don't understand. What do you mean by "a statement of futility"? In the dictionary, futility means "a total lack of purpose or usefulness."

Comment: @vin, that was a typo for "futurity."

Answer (score 2):

There is not much practical difference of meaning between your three examples. The same person might use any of them without intending any specific distinction.  Technically there are distinctions, and I will try to explain them. But these are in effect nuances, and you should not lay much stress on them.

Example 1:

The speaker by using "can" or "could" is inviting the listener to take an action, by describing the possible action. The speaker then indicates the response, the 'I will show you" Implicit in this is a conditional: "**If** you agree to do these moves then i will show you how.  "Will here is a simple prediction of a future event.

Example 2:

Technically, by omitting "can" or could" the speaker has moved into the imperative, giving an instruction, rather than making a suggestion. But this is a very mild instruction, and there is not really a significantly stronger intention here.

Example 3:

This is more of a description of a future event than an instruction I think, but again the effective meaning is still the same.

In practice there is no significant difference of intent among these there, the difference is a matter of style.